# nodesForXpath not always working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nodes, xmlnode

I am using the following code in my iOS  radio application:

```
nodes = [rootNode nodesForXPath:@"child::Station[Genres/Genre='Pop']" error:nil];
```

To get all radio stations with the Genre "POP" in the XML. for example, one of the stations would be:

```
    <Station>
<Name>(Top 40)</Name>
<Description>(Top 40)</Description>
<Genres><Genre>Pop</Genre></Genres>
<Logos><Logo><LogoUrl>http://blogs.slj.com/connect-the-pop/files/2013/05/Theatrics-logo-small.png</LogoUrl></Logo></Logos>
<Streams><Stream><MediaType>MP3</MediaType><BitRate>128</BitRate><StreamUrl>http://relay.radio.fm:1133/;stream</StreamUrl></Stream></Streams>
<Contacts><Contact type="General"><Name>Report Trouble</Name><Email>contact@email.com</Email><Facebook>http://www.facebook.com/</Facebook></Contact></Contacts>
</Station>
```

But I need to be able to get JUST the genres not the stations, so instead of the Pop stations, I would like to receive the list of Genres alone, after this I can have another `tableView` with the stations in the selected genre from the previous view...how can I get just the genres?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is enough...

```
  nodes = [rootNode nodesForXPath:@"//Genres" error:nil];
```

it will collect array of "Genres" then

ie:

**Output will be:**

```
<Genre>Pop</Genre>
<Genre>Pop1</Genre>
<Genre>Pop2</Genre>
.
.
.
.
```

like that

once again u need the value of "Genere" then follow the below code

```
  nodes = [rootNode nodesForXPath:@"//Genre" error:nil];
```

Comment: Can I do  nodes = [rootNode nodesForXPath:@"//Genres/Genre" error:nil]; to get the value of Genre?

Comment: i didn't tried yet i will try and let you know @RamGrg